# Structured-data throws error for the publisher and image

Tags: structured-data

There is a parent span including two itemtypes as below:

```
<span itemprop="publisher" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Organization">
        <meta itemprop="name" content="@Model.Brand.Name" />
        <span itemprop="logo" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/ImageObject">
            <link itemprop="url" href="@string.Format(Model.Brand.BrandAssetUrlPath+"{0}", "images/brand-logo-colored.png")" />
        </span>
    </span>
```

I am getting the errors for  LOGO and IMAGE which is : ***(MISSING_FIELD_WITHOUT_TYPE)***

I thought it could be because of wrapping the whole code within

```
itemtype="http://schema.org/Organization"
```

I removed that from the parent span but still not working.